# How to automatically use * wildcard on a Excel AutoFilter macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro in Excel that filters my table when it is activated by a button.

This is the macro:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        Range("D1").Value
End Sub
```

The macro is filtering the table using the field 2 and the value on D1 cell.

**How do I make it use the * wildcard?**

For example, if the name is `Maria Doe` and the cell is `Maria` it won't show in filter. But if the cell is `Maria*` it will show in filter.

I think the issue has to do with the `criteria:=` parameter, but I'm not sure how to set it.

Comment: `Criteria1:= Range("D1").Value & "*"`  ?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s) is an example :)

Comment: @chrisneilsen: That's a valid answer. You should have posted it as an answer :)

Comment: @chris neilsen, yes, this is the right way to do it, worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code. this shoud work. check and let me know:

```
Sub Macro2()
    '
    ' Macro2 Macro
    '

    '
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=" & Range("D2").Value & "*"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didnt work. Check @chris neilsen comment.